# Populate Data in Calculated Field in an Access Database Table

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a table which contains:

```
CostValue | SpentDateFrom | SpentDateTo | Jan2019 | Feb2019 | Mar2019 till Dec2019
```

Now I would like to populate the `costvalue` based on `spentdatefrom` to `spentdateTo`.

For example: if the cost value is 2000 and the start date is Jan2019 to Feb2019 then the value of 2000 should be populated to Jan and Feb 2019 Field.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use an UPDATE query. However, what you show as table structure doesn't make sense.

Comment: I will try it thank you! i know seems like that  :) just trying something if its possibly useful. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use “Calculated Field” as field type for the CostValue field.